# Python dict comparison is taking huge CPU usage

Tags: python

I am trying to compare `list_rpm_results` with `rpm_results`. I have reduced the count of items in the dictionaries to fit in here. I am able to fetch the required fields, but my problem is `list_rpm_results` has around 4000 records, and `rpm_results` has 15000 records. When I run the code below, CPU usage is crossing 100%. Can someone guide me how to optimize the code below, or is there any alternate way?

```
list_rpm_results = [
    {
        "id": "320b6bbb-9b06-45fe-9e34-bbbad64169ab",
        "title": "fix update",
        "bug_id": "0717",
        "type": "bugfix",
        "rpms": [
            "requests_x86_64.rpm",
            "htop_x86_64.rpm"
        ]
    }
]

rpm_results = {
    "requests_x86_64.rpm": {
        "rpm_name": "requests_x86_64.rpm",
        "sourcerpm": "requests_x86.rpm",
        "name": "requests",
        "checksum": "fae7b8a2b45f03bb3417c6d4cf97e66c545a5ad2"
    },
    "htop_x86_64.rpm": {
        "rpm_name": "htop_x86_64.rpm",
        "sourcerpm": "htop_x86.rpm",
        "name": "htop",
        "checksum": "21063b61c7032c9ff8788e4762d75bdddbffc99e"
    }
}

new_rpm_list = []
for item in list_rpm_results:
    rpms = item["rpms"]
    for pkg in rpms:
        if pkg in rpm_results.keys():
            new_rpm_list.append({
                "file_name": rpm_results[pkg]["name"],
                "check_sum": rpm_results[pkg]["checksum"],
                "bug_id": item["id"]
            })
print new_rpm_list
```

Comment: One detail: Instead of `if pkg in rpm_results.keys():` you can do simply `if pkg in rpm_results:`

Comment: Because we only have a small sample, I don;t know whether it would be more performant or not, but you could create sets of `{i['rpms'] for i in list_rpm_results}` and `set(rpm_results.keys())`, then find the intersection and only pull those keys. Set membership operations are way faster than list iteration, but building the sets may or may not take longer

Comment: Thank you Anderson, let me check once

Comment: just an interesting note: with 50000 entries, python3 does this in a jiffy, while python2 runs for over a minute (and counting...)

Answer (score 3):

The big problem here is you are using python2 so `rpm_results.keys()` produces a list, which must be searched through linearly. `dict`s already define `in` with constant average complexity, so use that.

Instead of

```
if pkg in rpm_results.keys():
```

use

```
if pkg in rpm_results:
```

Comment: That didnt improve.

Comment: @Auto-learner More than the CPU usage you should look at the execution time. Basic programs will always take 100% of a CPU when running unless you tell them to 'sleep', which is not something useful for this type of program

Comment: @Crivella , i have tried adding sleep but it will ultimately increase the execution time of the program. By removing rpm_results.key() , 3 seconds have been improved but my actual problem of CPU usage didnt resolve. Anyway thanks for the response.

Comment: @Auto-learner I think you misunderstood what i meant. For this type of calculation that do not require the process to sleep (since they are always actually using the CPU) you should expect to have a 100% use of one core of your CPU (which mean that any tangible improvement will be only on the execution time and not on the actual CPU load). Sleep is used only for stuff that actually need to sleep in the background until something happens. For this piece of code you posted, switching the line proposed in the answer actually seems to be the best optimization you could do

Answer (score 2):

The problem is is the line `if pkg in rpm_results.keys():`.  Here you are converting the keys to a list, then scanning the list to look for a particular key. This is not only an expensive pair of operations, you are converting the keys to a list for each package you check.  While converting to a list once would improve thins some, never doing that conversion and letting the dictionary use its hash table lookup is even better.  Simply changing to `if pkg in rpm_results:` should be a significant improvement.

```
new_rpm_list = []
for item in list_rpm_results:
    rpms = item["rpms"]
    for pkg in rpms:
    if pkg in rpm_results:
        new_rpm_list.append({
            "file_name": rpm_results[pkg]["name"],
            "check_sum": rpm_results[pkg]["checksum"],
            "bug_id": item["id"]
        })
print new_rpm_list
```

Answer (score 1):

Original:

```
new_rpm_list = []
for item in list_rpm_results:
    rpms = item["rpms"]
    for pkg in rpms:
        if pkg in rpm_results.keys():
            new_rpm_list.append({
                "file_name": rpm_results[pkg]["name"],
                "check_sum": rpm_results[pkg]["checksum"],
                "bug_id": item["id"]
            })
print new_rpm_list
```

Will ignore the fact that you are adding a `_` to checksum, but that seems weird.

Stage 1:
- inlined `item["rpms"]` (no effect on speed)
- removed `.keys()` large speedup on python2 - this changes list creation + list search `(2x O(n))` into a hash lookup `O(1)`

```
new_rpm_list = []
for item in list_rpm_results:
    for pkg in item["rpms"]:
        if pkg in rpm_results:
            new_rpm_list.append({
                "file_name": rpm_results[pkg]["name"],
                "check_sum": rpm_results[pkg]["checksum"],
                "bug_id": item["id"]
            })
print new_rpm_list
```

If you didn't need the item id, you could also find all missing rpm at once, which would be slightly faster.